# Python Input Text into The Next Empty Cell of an Excel Sheet Column for Multiple Workbooks

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have 30 workbooks with naming convention (`myfile1.xlsm`, `myfile2.xlsm`, `myfile3.xlsm`, .. etc). I would like to input a text into the next empty cell of a specific column `Q` of a specific worksheet `sheet1` for all 30 workbooks. The code below works perfect for one workbook but I need to do same thing for all 30 workbooks so I am trying to put it in a python function, how do I put the code below in a function so I can apply it to all 30 files at the same time?

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import Cell

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/me/randomfolder/myfile1.xlsm',  keep_vba=True)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

#insert text in the first empty cell in column Q starting from cell Q5
for row in ws['Q5:Q1000']:
cell = row[0]
if cell.value is None:
    cell.value = 'random text'
    break

#save file
wb.save(r'C:/Users/me/randomfolder/myfile1.xlsm')
```

Comment: Is your question "how do I write a function in Python?" Or do you have a more specific problem? How to loop over a range of numbers? How to pass those numbers to the function you're calling? How to insert those numbers into a file name?

Comment: @Grismar I guess my real question is how to get my code above to work for all 30 files at the same time

Comment: Waht have you tried yourself? Have you tried putting the code you have in a function? Have you tried something to loop over the files you need processed? You say you're "trying to put it in a Python `def`", but there's no `def` in the code you shared. Since it's just a matter of indenting the code and putting `def name():` at the start - like any tutorial on functions will start by telling you, where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: @Grismar I am new to python I just know how to write the code to work for one workbook but I don't know how to loop it over all the files or put in the a  `def ` function that is where i am getting stuck hence the reason there is no  `def` in my code, I have watched tutorials but cannot figure out how to implement it for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.xlsm` files are located in the same directory (in your case, `"C:/Users/me/randomfolder"`), you can then use [**`Path.glob`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) to return their paths and pass them as a parameter of [**`openpyxl.load_workbook`**](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) one by one in a for loop.

Try this :

```
from pathlib import Path
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.cell import Cell


files_directory = "C:/Users/me/randomfolder"

for file in Path(files_directory).glob("*.xlsm"):
    
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file,  keep_vba=True)
    ws = wb["Sheet1"]

    #insert text in the first empty cell in column Q starting from cell Q5
    for row in ws['Q5:Q1000']:
        cell = row[0]
        if cell.value is None:
            cell.value = 'random text'
            break

    #save file
    wb.save(file)
```

Comment: Thanks@abokey, it runs with no errors but doesn't input the text into any of the files. I appreciate the help, you have given me pointer and a sense of direction, I was previously directionless on how to approach it, I will tweak and play around with it some to see how to get it to execute the task

Comment: I forgot to put the wildcard. We should use `.glob("*.xlsm")` and there was bad indentation in the second for loop. I updated my answer. The code should do the job this time ;)

Comment: Thanks! @abokey I didn't catch it, I was busy looking at everything else, you just saved me from going down a rabbit hole. It works perfect now, it inputted the text for all the files.

Comment: You're welcome @ohmandy. Glad to be helpful ;)